# Move a file from a directory to another

Tags: filters, uploads

I have this function:

```
function attachment_selectbox_edit($form_fields, $post) {

$select_options = array(
    "no" => "No",
    "yes" => "Yes"
);

// get the current value of our custom field
$current_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_my_select", true);

// build the html for our select box
$mySelectBoxHtml = "<select name='attachments[{$post->ID}][my_select]' id='attachments[{$post->ID}][my_select]'>";
foreach($select_options as $value => $text){

    // if this value is the current_value we'll mark it selected
    $selected = ($current_value == $value) ? ' selected ' : '';

    // escape value for single quotes so they won't break the html
    $value = addcslashes( $value, "'");

    $mySelectBoxHtml .= "<option value='{$value}' {$selected}>{$text}</option>";
}
$mySelectBoxHtml .= "</select>";

// add our custom select box to the form_fields
$form_fields["my_select"]["label"] = __("Move the file?");
$form_fields["my_select"]["input"] = "html";
$form_fields["my_select"]["html"] = $mySelectBoxHtml;

return $form_fields;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "attachment_selectbox_edit", null, 2);
```

I want to move the file from "uploads" directory to "uploads/new-directory" when $current_value == 'yes'.

Can you help me?

Comment: is `/new-directory` exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists. Any ideas to move the file?

Comment: I don't think will work. You'll got issue if there are too many crop images in old folder that need to move progmatically in WP.

Comment: on what page are you intending to use this form?

Comment: I want to use it when editing an attachment of the media library. It is posible to edit title, caption, description... but I would like the option of moving the file from one folder to another.

Answer (score 2):

Can't seem to track down the right filter to process this in just yet (where the edit form is being saved), especially since `attachment_fields_to_edit` can be used in multiple places. But maybe you already know? This will give you a good start anyway...

```
add_filter('??attachment_fields_save_filter??','move_attachment_directory',10,2);

function move_attachment_directory($form_fields,$post) {

$attach_id = $post->ID;
if (!isset($_POST['attachments'][$attach_id]['my_select'])) {return;}
if ($_POST['attachments'][$attach_id]['my_select'] == 'no') {return;}

// set directories
$uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
$newdirectory = 'new-directory'; // or whatever it is

// get attachment metadata
$attachdata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attach_id);

// move original image
$filepath = trailingslashit($uploaddir).$attachdata['file'];
$newfilepath = trailingslashit($uploaddir).trailingslashit($newdirectory).$attachdata['file'];
rename($filepath,$newfilepath);
$attachdata['file'] = trailingslashit($newdirectory).$attachdata['file'];

// move each attachment size too
foreach ($attachdata['sizes'] as $size => $data) {
    $file = $data['file'];
    $filepath = trailingslashit($uploaddir).$data['file'];
    $newfilepath = trailingslashit($uploaddir).trailingslashit($newdirectory).$data['file'];
    rename($filepath,$newfilepath);
    $data['file'] = trailingslashit($newdirectory).$data['file'];
    $attachdata['sizes'][$size] = $data;
}

// update attachment metadata
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,$attachdata);

}
```

Note: I don't think this will work as is if you have media sorted by month/year on.

In any case this is untested code and may have path bugs etc., so may need some work in a test environment, but it shows it can be done and hopefully it gets you to the next step...